# Java Window Duplication Prevention

Tags: java, swing, duplicates

```
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Register Student");
btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        RegisterStudent panel_1 = new RegisterStudent();
        panel_1.setVisible(true);
    }
});
btnNewButton.setBounds(0, 162, 167, 37);
panel.add(btnNewButton);
```

Is there a way, that IF one specific window is open already, it cant be opened once again?
Because, i don't want the user to click on a button several times, causing several windows to be opened with the same content?

Comment: Make the 'window' a modal dialog.  It would solve the problem with the default behavior.  Also, don't set the 'bounds' of anything.  That leads to a very fragile GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the panel_1 variable outside of the mouse listener block and initialize it to null.  When the mouse is clicked, check if panel_1 is null, and if it is, create it.

```
final RegisterStudent panel_1 = new RegisterStudent();
JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Register Student");
btnNewButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        panel_1.setVisible(true);
    }
});
btnNewButton.setBounds(0, 162, 167, 37);
panel.add(btnNewButton);
```

Comment: Hi @Tony , I have just tried it your way, but it shows error messages?
If I do it exactly as you wrote it then it would underline all the panel_1 in the code saying cannot refer to a non final variable panel_1 inside an inner class definer in a different method. when i then change the modifier of panel_1 to final, it would underline panel_1 in your line 7 saying the final local variable panel_1 cannot be assigned, since its not defined in an enclosing type? could you please advise?

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  panel_1 needs to be declared as final in order to be used inside an inner class.  You will need to instantiate the variable when it is created.

Comment: how do i go around my error though? because its showing up an error in line 7 as i said? what can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of all open windows from `Window.getWindows()` since 1.6 or all open Frames with `Frame.getFrames()` since 1.2.  You can use the name property or the window class (RegisterStudent) to test if the windows is already open and set the focus on it instead open another one.